# issue with jquery.carouFredSel responsive slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Pls check this link, http://provenwebconcepts.nl/VE/

This site is responsive, but slider is not responsive, if you resize browser screen, you can see the issue, after refreshing the page, it becomes okay for that particular screen.

I have applied it from this site, http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/
So can anyone help me to make this slider responsive?

or if you can provide any reference link of responsive slider with similar functionality, that would be great.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: If you are OK with using plugins, check this out: http://bxslider.com/

Comment: thx, but this is not of the same functionality, normally i used many responsive slideshows, but in this, clicking left or right photo makes it slide to next and previous slide.

Comment: You can do the same with this plugin. Your example web site has some blur rectangle div on each sides. And on this plugin's site , there are arrow keys instead of those divs. You can replace them easily.

Comment: I just checked now, but in this one image is showing in an container, even if i take 100% width of the slider, other images get display none dynamically.